# Laravel use select inside whereHas

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

Hi i'm having some truble figuring how to use select inside a wherehas query or i'm i doing in the wrong way ?
the query work but it's not selecting.

```
 $query = $query->whereHas('orderProducts', function($q){

            $q->select(DB::raw('SUM(order_product.total) AS spent_total'));
            $q->select(DB::raw('COUNT(order_product.box_id) as box_count'));

        });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

try `$q->addSelect()` instead of `$q->select()`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries#selects